# While trying to make splash screen with in flutter I am getting an error 255 how do I fix it?

Tags: flutter, dart, splash-screen, pubspec

I was trying to make a flutter splash screen using flutter_splash_screen package but i keep getting this error while running this command
**flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:create**

my flutter also upgraded so there is no problem with it, maybe there is a problem with pubspec file which I can't figure it out anyone can help me out with it

```
> flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:create Unhandled exception:
> Exception: Your `pubspec.yaml` file does not contain a
> `flutter_native_splash` section.
> #1      createSplash (package:flutter_native_splash/flutter_native_splash.dart:21:16)
> #2      main.<anonymous closure> (file:///C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_native_splash-1.2.4/bin/create.dart:8:28)
> #3      Parser.parse.<anonymous closure> (package:args/src/parser.dart:106:15)
> #4      _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:400:8)
> #6      Parser.parse (package:args/src/parser.dart:95:22)
> #8      main (file:///C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_native_splash-1.2.4/bin/create.dart:9:10)
> #9      _delayEntrypointInvocation.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:281:32)
> #10     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:184:12) pub finished with exit
> code 255 PS C:\Users\mosam\Desktop\Price Stories App UI\splashscreen>
> flutter clean Deleting .dart_tool...                                  
> 975ms Deleting .packages...                                           
> 1ms Deleting Generated.xcconfig...                                    
> 1ms Deleting flutter_export_environment.sh...                         
> 1ms PS C:\Users\mosam\Desktop\Price Stories App UI\splashscreen>
> flutter pub get Running "flutter pub get" in splashscreen...          
> 1,662ms PS C:\Users\mosam\Desktop\Price Stories App UI\splashscreen>
> flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:create Unhandled exception:
> Exception: Your `pubspec.yaml` file does not contain a
> `flutter_native_splash` section.
> #0      getConfig (package:flutter_native_splash/flutter_native_splash.dart:155:5)
> #1      createSplash (package:flutter_native_splash/flutter_native_splash.dart:21:16)
> #2      main.<anonymous closure> (file:///C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_native_splash-1.2.4/bin/create.dart:8:28)
> #3      Parser.parse.<anonymous closure> (package:args/src/parser.dart:106:15)
> #4      _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:400:8)
> #5      MapView.forEach (dart:collection/maps.dart:342:10)
> #6      Parser.parse (package:args/src/parser.dart:95:22)
> #7      ArgParser.parse (package:args/src/arg_parser.dart:335:42)
> #8      main (file:///C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_native_splash-1.2.4/bin/create.dart:9:10)
> #9      _delayEntrypointInvocation.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:281:32)
> #10     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:184:12) pub finished with exit
> code 255
```

Here is my Pubspec file :

```
**name: splashscreen
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
    

flutter_splash_native:
    color: "#fffff"
    image:  assets/appui.jpg
    android: true
    ios: true

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
    cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
    

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_native_splash: ^1.2.4

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have named your `flutter_native_splash` section wrong... you named it `flutter_splash_native`.  Also, your color code should have six digits, not five.  This is how the section should appear:

```yaml
flutter_native_splash:
  color: "#ffffff"
  image:  assets/appui.jpg
  android: true
  ios: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Align  flutter_native_splash: ^1.2.4 just like  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2 file is not aligned properly

Comment: Now pubget command is showing error 65

Comment: comment here let me see

Comment: align the pubspec file properly this is the problem you are facing, create a new project and check the alignment from it

Answer (score 0):

make sure you run

```
flutter clean
```

then

```
flutter pub get
```

lastly

```
flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:create
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).